# Why does using keycloak Autowired is null?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I create Bean from Keycloak , for example :

```
  @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloakInstance() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                .realm(MASTER_REALM)
                .clientId(CLIENT_ID_ADMIN_CLI)
                .username(USER_NAME)
                .password(PASSWORD)
                .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET_ADMIN_CLI)
                .build();
    }
```

and Autowired Keycloak to other class but when time I want this :
RealmResource develop = keycloak.realm("develop"); `

but keycloak is null

how I can solve it .